# algorithm context overlapping footer

Tags: header-footer, algorithm2e

I am using `algorithm2e` for my algorithm, the algo is a bit long and I need two pages for proper formatting and readability.

When I compile, the algorithm instead of splitting into next page prints on the same page but it overlaps the footer.

I have tried the `\thispagestyle{empty}` but it is not picking the page where algorithm is located instead it clears the previous page or next page mean if the algor is on 2 page, it clears either 1st or 3rd page and not exactly the 2nd page.

Isn't there any command to direct the algorithm to break line and go to next page?

I tried to add new lines, pages but with no success.

Comment: Not really... not for [`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e). You should be able to do this manually... perhaps.

Comment: i changed the font size to force it to occupy one page

Answer (score 1):

If you use `fancyhdr` to do the page headers and footers, you can use

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot[C]{\iffloatpage{}{\thepage}}
```

This will suppress the page number (footer) on floatpages.
Similarly, there is `\iftopfloat` and if `\ifbotfloat`.

If the danger for an overlapping float is over later in the document, you can then insert the simpler definition

```
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
```